# Why is Visual Studio changing control positions & sizes automatically?

Tags: winforms

I noticed that when I've made small changes to existing Winforms code, numerous control locations are modified by Visual Studio automatically.

Example --

Original:

```
this.btnHelp.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(721, 444);
```

Changed:

```
this.btnHelp.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(556, 242);
```

Depending on the form there could be many of these. It looks like probably every control with a `Size` or `Location` property has been modified. Consistently made smaller, actually.

To be clear, no one made these changes manually. And oddly, I can't really detect any difference when running the app - though the changes seem numerically large enough to be noticed.

The only thing I can think of is a recent update from VS2015 to VS2019, but that's just a guess.

Comment: The changes are made by the designer due to the Form.AutoScaleMode property being set toe either `Font` or `Dpi` and there being a difference in the system dpi settings between the time the form was last saved and the current setting.  You should also be seeing a change in the Form.AutoScaleDimensions property that is set in the designer file.

Comment: @TnTinMn thanks that makes some sense - though there have been no DPI changes. Would something like switching monitors cause this? Also as it stands I can no longer reproduce it... I wonder if it was a VS2019 quirk.

Comment: Not a VS2019 quirk; it is a scaling issue that has been around for a long time. DPI changes with changing the Window's Display settings Scale Factor (100%,150%,175%, etc).  Default font has changed over time along with  measurement metrics.  Repro is easy, create a new Winform project and place a Label at (10,10) on it and click save.  Open the form's designer file and note the `AutoScalexxx` properties. Go back to the form and change the forms Font's size to twice the current value and then go inspect the label's location.  It will be at(19,19).

Comment: This is why recommendation is to design at 100% scaling (96 dpi). VS2017 and 2019 throw up a banner to tell you to do so (assuming you have not disabled it via the options), but I have never got the automatic reset option to work.  You can do via the registry as discussed in [Disable DPI-awareness in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/disable-dpi-awareness?view=vs-2019).